# images are not displaying properly in one page

Tags: html, css, magento

one of our page is not displaying properly here
[image]

means, 1) images are not displayed properly

2)`Device Design Category Sort By` options are not displayed.

3)on right side , "Now accepting paypal" is displaying.

But all other pages are working fine like here

[image]

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.main-container a {
    color: #ff7704;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, is that for the page that isn't showing the products properly, you have a sidebar active on the right side. The same one which is showing the Paypal logo. You probably need to choose a template/layout without sidebar in your CMS.

Comment: i am using same configuration for both categories. how to choose a template/layout without sidebar in CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Your page is working fine for 1-column layout. The page in which you are having issue is at 3-column layout. Change layout to 1-column or fix your 3-column layout issue.

Comment: in backend, it set for `No layout updates`. also i tried chnaging every column layout, but stil its giving same result for all layouts.

Answer (score 0):

it was problem with Anchor category, once we set the Anchor category to "YES" , its working fine